# Comparing 2 strings from a struct

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, typedef, fifo

I don't program in C for a good 2 years, I recently was ordered to make a program that uses a FIFO system, I'm really confused about how I'm going to search for a name using this method.

This is my struct:

```
struct Node {
  int price;
  char plat[25];
  char name[50];
  struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node node;
```

This is where I insert:

```
void insert(node *LINE) {
  line *new = alocar();
  new->next = NULL;

  if (empty(LINE))
    LINE->next = new;
  else {
    node *tmp = LINE->next;

    while (tmp->next != NULL)
      tmp = tmp->next;

    tmp->next = new;
  }
  size++;
}
```

Here is where I'm struggling, I'm just freestyling at this point, trying to figure out what works but nothing seems to be working, I'm trying to search for the name inside the struct using the `nameu` variable.

```
void search(node*LINE)
{
  if(empty(LINE))
  {
    printf("Line empty!\n\n");
    return;
  }
  // -------------------test----------------------
  char nameu[10];
  node *tmp;
  node n;

  if (scanf("%9s", nameu) != 1) return;
  while( tmp != NULL && strcmp(nameu, n.name) == 0)
  {
    printf("%6s", tmp->name);
    tmp = tmp->prox;
  }
}
```

The full code is in Portuguese so I only placed snippets of code that I translated, I'll post here the full code with translations only in the menu so that anyone trying to use it can comprehend what's going on.

[https://pastebin.com/ZytqhcWF](https://pastebin.com/zRRSWFwX)

Edit: Thanks to Dimitri and the others I found the cause of it not printing, here is the result.

```
void search(node*LINE)
{
  if(empty(LINE))
  {
    printf("Line empty!\n\n");
    return;
  }
// -------------------test----------------------
char nameu[10];
node *tmp;
tmp = LINE->next;
node n;
    
if (scanf("%9s", nameu) != 1) return;
while (tmp)
{
  if (!strcmp(nameu, tmp->name))
  {
    printf("%6s", tmp->name);
    break;
  }
  tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

Comment: what do you think n.nome should be?

Comment: @johnelemans I forgot to translate it, but I was trying to use it to compare since I don't remember how to compare in this way

Comment: `tmp` is uninitialised when first entering the `while` loop (in `search()`)

Comment: The problem is you're comparing a non-existant string `n.name`. The variable n is a struct but never has a string assigned to it's name field.

Comment: Also, your loop executes until the names *don't* match (or `tmp` becomes NULL)

Comment: `while (tmp) { if (!strcmp(nameu, tmp->name) { printf("%6s", tmp->name); break; } tmp = tmp->next; }`